# Different sized Grid Python 3.00

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a game that includes a grid that can be resized and every tile must be modifiable. The way that I am doing it now requires many variables. Is there any easier way to do this? Thanks!

```
t1 = "?"
t2 = "?"
t3 = "?"
t4 = "?"
t5 = "?"
t6 = "?"
t7 = "?"
t8 = "?"
t9 = "?"

print(t1 + t2 + t3)
print(t4 + t5 + t6)
print(t7 + t8 + t9)

#???
#???
#???
```

Comment: Look into [loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm).

Comment: I don't think that there is any way to loop making new variables, right? I am generally new to Python3 so correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: lists can store your variables as elements, and after you can iterate over them with loops.